# Iframe border issue in IE8

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add iframe in my page. Its working fine in all the browser except IE8.

I have checkout `stackoverflow.com`. Many of the suggestion would be `frameBorder="0"`. My scenario is i dont have a access to edit the line . so i tried using java script `setAttribute` but unfortunately its not working in `IE8`.

```
function removeBorder()
{
    document.getElementById("myframe").frameBorder="0";
}
```

Is there any possibility to create dynamic Attribute ?

Could you please help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you are calling `removeBorder` and where? from head tag or somewhere else in the html

Comment: One of these should work:
document.getElementById("myframe").setAttribute("frameBorder",0);
document.getElementById("myframe").removeAttribute("frameBorder");

Answer (score 1):

this is the proper way to create an attribute in js

```
var att=document.createAttribute("frameBorder");
att.value = "0";
document.getElementById("myframe").setAttributeNode(att);
```

source : [**W3S**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createattribute.asp)

advice : read more about DOM elements and how to manipulate them